# Android: setX() or setTranslationX() does not change the position of adjacent view

Tags: android, layout

I have 2 buttons in the following layout. Buttons are adjusted such that left button always remains to the left of right button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right Button" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/left_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_btn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

But, In my activity, when I change the position of right button, the left button position remains same.

```
Button rightBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_btn);
rightBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.setTranslationX(100);
    }
});
```

[image]

I have used both `setTranslationX(100)` as well as `setX(500)` to right button, but the left button position remains same. I am not sure but came to know that `setTranslationX` only change the appearance of button, but the object remains at the same position.

Is there any property to set the position of right button so that left button position also changes so that it is always to the left of right button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when I change the position of right button, the left button position remains same.`

That is because you explicitly moving the right button x-axis not the whole layout thus right button is only translated to the position you specify and not the left button as well.

Solution:

You can translate the left button as well when the right button is moved same translationx pixels.

Comment: So, in the Relative layout, even if we specify the left button to be left side of right button, it doesn't work, but changing the width of right button explicitly changes the position of left button correctly.

Comment: @DileepPerla changing the width is different, and yes it will automatically changes the position of the left. Button because you are not playing around with its position but merely just changing the width of the right button itself.

Comment: setTranslationX has no effect on layout of other components. It happens post layout by relative layout.

Answer (score -2):

I think one of the issues you seem to be having is that you're using

```
view.setTranslationX(100);
```

in a RelativeLayout which means you're kind of using it like an AbsoluteLayout (which in itself is deprecated).

Try to rethink your strategy.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand the `which in itself is deprecated`.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout has been deprecated since Android API level 3 (the recent ones are API level 20), basically it is not something you should be using it what this means.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html